# Unable to do inline editing as edit button is overriden

Tags: button, salesforce, overriding, inline, edit

How can I enable inline edit in Salesforce?

1. my edit page is overriden with visualforce page.
2. I don't want to override by view button.
3. Is there any possibly I can get inline editing back?

Answer (score 0):

Don't override the Edit button. You instructed SF that editing has to be done differently, what did you expect?

If you really need to - put on the page the "Custom Edit" as a separate button and maybe try to hide the original "Edit".

Comment: thankyou for the quick response.still facing this issue. Let me provide some more details on that:1) previously my view button was overriden with vf page. There it was have apex:detail tag with inlineEdit set to true. But the requirements was to remove that page. Since my edit page is also overriden I am not able to see inline edit at all. I don't want to override view button as it is not allowing me to have feed view enabled. I want both feed view as well as inline edit at the same time.

Comment: Have you actually tried what I wrote. To remove the override and if there is special functionality, custom edit needed - make it exactly that, a new custom button. Have you considered moving to o lightning experience. You'll have feed-like components and inline edit